# Why was this question closed as not a real question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This question was closed: [create unique verification link in email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303603/create-unique-verification-link-in-email) . But "Is this possible?" is a real question (though the answer is obvious if anyone's used any web app at all :-), and asking for pointers is legit. As submitted it's not a great question, but why close it, Corbin, Colin, Kermit, Alain, and Tchoupi? Nick's answer is really helpful, and wouldn't exist for searchers like me if the question hadn't been asked. So it is: 1) a real question that 2) fostered a useful answer.

Comment: Also see: [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question)

Comment: @Makoto's answer is super helpful - thank you. The immediate down-votes though - seems pretty harsh. This is my first time asking a meta question, I'm a good SO citizen, and, in my own defense, it's a little hard to orient due to the nature of meta, and because it seems many answers could be "already answered" ones. Tough love.

Comment: Keep in mind that Meta site voting is different than main-site voting. Main site voting is a reflection of question quality; while Meta voting *can* be a reflection of question quality, conventionally it's more a reflection of agreement or disagreement. For example, I downvoted because I disagree with your claim that the linked question is a real question (I think it *deserved* to be closed as "not a real question"), *not* because of anything about the quality of your post. I can't speak for anyone else's voting, but my vote simply means "I disagree," *not* "I think this is a bad post."

Comment: *Is this possible.* [punches a baby] *And if so can someone please share any tutorials or tell me where i woudl start with this?* [punches all the babies]

Comment: "asking for pointers is legit" not really. It's mainly too broad and unclear.

Answer (score 17):

"Not a real question" is a deprecated close reason.  In the case of *this* question, it's been replaced by:

- **Too broad** - the question "is it possible" is not constrained enough to give a useful answer.  *Most* of the time, "yes" is the response to that, which leads into a bit of back-and-forth.  Not what we want to foster.
- **Looking for external resources** - the OP explicitly calls out that they want guides and tutorials.  That's *definitely* not something we provide here.

Above all the OP doesn't even know where to begin.  It's good that this question's closed, even if "not a real question" was a bit contentious of a reason.

Comment: Related: [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question)